# Remote object implementation with RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, remoteobject

Suppose that I'm having an interface whose actual implementation resides in the service:

```
public ISomeRemoteObject
{
    void SomeMethod(string arg);
    int SomeMethodWithResult();
}
```

I want to be able to call these methods from the client via AMQP, preferably RabbitMQ.
What I could do is something like:

```
public RemoteObjectStub : ISomeRemoteObject
{
    public void SomeMethod(string arg)
    {
        //use RabbitMQ to notify service that SomeMethod() has been called with arg parameter
        //and the ID of the object in case there are multiple instances
    }

    public int SomeMethodWithResult()
    {
        //use RabbitMQ RPC to make a synchronous call and get the result
    }
}
```

Another alternative is to make a code generator that will take the interface and generate the stub.
But I don't know if this is better as well, as where I used to work I've seen people struggling with similar solutions.

Although these things *might* work, this isn't what my application actually sells and I want to avoid doing the plumbing myself.
Is there any library or project (paid, free, open source doesn't matter) to automate the process?